# C++ Byte Buffer Manipulation

Tags: c++, graphics, rendering

I'm trying to make a vertex buffer abstraction for my 3D renderer and I want to be able to store the vertex attribute data as a byte buffer than can be restored latter to the "original" format but I'm not so sure how to do the latter.

I only have a function that converts a vector of type T to a byte array:

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<uint8_t> toBytes(const std::vector<T>& src) {
    const auto buff_size = src.size() * sizeof(T);
    std::vector<uint8_t> buffer(buff_size);

    std::memcpy(buffer.data(), src.data(), buff_size);

    return buffer;
}
```

But still I'm not sure how to rebuild the array like in this snippet:

```
class Buffer
{
public:

...

    template<typename T>
    std::vector<T> getData() const;

private:

    std:vector<uint8_t> m_bytes;
};

struct Vertex
{
    vec3 position;
    vec3 normal;
    ...
};

// Fill vector with multiple Vertex instances
std::vector<Vertex> vertices = {...};

std::vector<float> raw_vertex_data = {
  // Positions      // Texture Coords
  1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f
};

Buffer buffer_a{toBytes(vertices)};
Buffer buffer_b{toBytes(raw_vertex_data)};

...

const std::vector<Vertex> vertex_buffer = buffer_a.getData<Vertex>();
const std::vector<float>  float_buffer = buffer_b.getData<float>();
```

**NOTE:** It would be nice to have a reference (e.g. `const std::vector<T>&`) instead of a copy of the data but don't know if its possible.

Comment: If you limit yourself to trivially-copyable and default-constructible `T`, you can just do the same as for the other direction, just with the types swapped and size adjusted.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I think I can live with those constraints but I wonder if making copies of the data will cause performance issues (maybe not noticeable?). Also, I was wondering if there's a way to reinterpret the vector with a cast or something, do you happen to know that?

Comment: There is no way to reinterpret the vector without a copy. However, if you have a vector of `T` you can reinterpret_cast the result of `.data()` to a pointer to `unsigned char` (aka `std::uint8_t`) and pass that as e.g. a `std::span`, because there is an aliasing exception _to_ (but not _from_) `unsigned char`.